# How to calculate accuracy for facial recognition system?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, biometrics

I am new to Biometric Evaluation and I wish to plot the ROC curve, CMC curve, and Genuine Vs Imposter Distribution. I trained the model on my dataset based on https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/18/face-recognition-with-opencv-python-and-deep-learning/. If I give a test image, it is working correctly.
But, I do not know how to get a genuine and imposter score based on this method for the entire Test Dataset.

Comment: sum of right recognitions divided by the sum of right & wrong recognitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All state-of-the-art models such as VGG-Face, FaceNet or DeepFace are tested on LFW (Labeled Faces in the Wild) data set. Luckily, Scikit learn offers this data set as an out-of-the-box function.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_lfw_pairs
fetch_lfw_pairs = fetch_lfw_pairs(subset = 'test', color = True, resize = 1)
pairs = fetch_lfw_pairs.pairs
labels = fetch_lfw_pairs.target
```

Now, you should test each pair with your model.

```
predictions = []
for i in range(0, pairs.shape[0]):
   pair = pairs[i]
   img1 = pair[0]
   img2 = pair[1]
   prediction = verify(img1, img2) #this should return 1 for same person, 0 for different persons.
   predictions.append(prediction)
```

Then, you should compare predictions and labels.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
score = accuracy_score(labels, predictions)
```

Besides, you can calculate some other metrics

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
    
precision = precision_score(actuals, predictions)
recall = recall_score(actuals, predictions)
f1 = f1_score(actuals, predictions)
```

Comment: {AttributeError}'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'target'. At least from 0.24.0

Comment: `lfw_pairs_test.target` will work instead.